# Conditional Single SQL Query Insert

Tags: sql

Let say I have a TABLE called:

```
 EMP(Eid,Ename,ESalary)
```

Now I have to write a single query that will update:

```
if employee's salary >= 20000 then increment 25% else update 15% salary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update EMP
   set ESalary = CASE WHEN salary >= 20000
                      THEN salary * 1.25
                      ELSE salary * 1.15
                      END;
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. i forgot about case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update emp a set esalrary = 
(select (case when esalary >=20000 then esalary+(esalary*25/100) 
else  esalary+(esalary*25/100) end) from emp b where a.eid=b.eid);
```